# This error is keep coming const err = MongooseError(message);

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I just started ExpressJS and MongoDB and I'm trying to connect to MongoDB compass by localhost but I'm getting the same error. Can anyone please help me??[This is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSnpY.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that you cannot start without starting your constructor with "New". So, the syntax should be `const err = new MongooseError(message)`